# MSI installer PostBuild Event

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Under Visual Studio 2010, I am trying to create msi installer for two projects, and the build with:

> Error 5   'PostBuildEvent' failed with error code '1' 'Unspecified
> error'

However, when I go inside the log I see:

> Packaging file 'adxloader.dll'...
>
> Packaging file 'Extensibility.dll'...
>
> Starting post-build events...
>
> The system cannot find the path specified.

However, my setup files are correctly created. It looks like after they are created Visual Studio is trying to copy them somewhere else. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It will be great if you can post the content of your post build event.

Comment: how do I find it? I just created a setup project for my project

Comment: You can find it if you open your project in Visual Studio and go for Properties and select Build Events tab.

Comment: there is nothing ! The Post Build event is apparently added by the setup file..

Comment: By Setup file do you mean the MSBuild or there is a different setup project itself. Can you please post the content of this from the setup file in that case.?

Comment: In case anyone stumbleds upon this after another 7 years, To edit build events in Installer projects you have to edit the PreBuildEvent and PostBuildEvent in the tiny little properties box below the Solution Explorer.  When you click into it then a dialog box will open up with a larger edit window.  This is unlike the application properties tabs that you normally get